# Redirect browser-enabled InfoPath form to custom URL

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath2010

In my InfoPath Form, I have a button and I want to redirect to a custom URL on click.
I have tried `Response.Redirect`, `Server.Transfer` and `SPUtilities.Redirect` but none of them work.

When I tried

```
HttpContext.Response.Redirect("http://google.com", false);
```

My form shows the error message: Critical error...

Comment: You can use custom asp.net page which hosts browser-enabled form in a XmlFormView control and redirect after button clicked with javascript.

Comment: Would help to provide errors for all the options you tried and the FULL error message (not the truncated critical error you have for the last one).

Answer (score 0):

You can not redirect when you published InfoPath Forms Services but can host your browser-enabled InfoPath form on your own XmlFormView webpart and then notify host to redirect.
Here is my solution:
You can use the NotifyHost method of the XmlForm class to send notifications to the hosting environment of a form template.
Add the following code to the Button control’s Clicked event handler:

```
NotifyHost("Redirect")
```

The **NotifyHost** method raises the **NotifyHost** event of the **XmlFormView** control.
Create VisualWebPart project and add **XmlFormView** control to VisualWebPart, you must add

`OnNotifyHost="XmlFormView1_NotifyHost"`

and

`XsnLocation="http://ServerName/FormServerTemplates/MyFormTemplate.xsn"`
to the control tag of XmlFormView1. The following code shows how to do this:

```
<cc1:XmlFormView ID="XmlFormView1" runat="server" XsnLocation="http://ServerName/FormServerTemplates/MyFormTemplate.xsn" OnNotifyHost="XmlFormView1_NotifyHost" />
```

After you hook up the event, you must implement the XmlFormView1_NotifyHost event handler in the code-behind of the VisualWebPart as follows:

```
protected void XmlFormView1_NotifyHost(object sender, NotifyHostEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Once you have hooked up the NotifyHost event to an event handler, you can write code in the event handler to register and execute JScript code.

```
protected void XmlFormView1_NotifyHost(object sender, NotifyHostEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Notification == "Redirect")
    {
        string jsCode = "window.location='http://www.google.com';";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "RedirectScript", jsCode, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks you, i finish this job, i used hyperlink and build dynamic link for it :D